# Query on .insert() function in maps for C++ STL

Tags: c++, error-handling, stl, g++

I am having quite a lot of trouble in implementing the map.insert() function in my code mentioned below :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
void add_edge(vector<int> v[],int v1,int v2){
    v[v1].push_back(v2);
    v[v2].push_back(v1);
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int e;
    cin>>e;
    vector<int> graph[n];
    map<int,int> m;
    pair<int,int> edges;
    for(int i=0;i<e;i++){
        int x,y,dist;
        cin>>x>>y>>dist;
        edges.first = x;
        edges.second = y;
        add_edge(graph,x,y);
        m.insert(edges,dist);
    }
}
```

Using the above code, I was trying to implement Prim's algorithm, wherein *x* and *y* are the edges of the graph, and *dist* is the respective weight of edge between *x* and *y*. Whenever I execute this code, I get this lengthy error message :

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:32:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map::insert(std::pair&, int&)’
         m.insert(edges,dist);
                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/map:61:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/stdc++.h:81,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:731:7: note: candidate: std::pair, std::_Select1st >, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Allocator>::rebind >::other>::iterator, bool> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const value_type&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = int; _Compare = std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >; typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair, std::_Select1st >, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Allocator>::rebind >::other>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = std::pair]
       insert(const value_type& __x)
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:731:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:739:9: note: candidate: template std::pair, std::_Select1st >, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Allocator>::rebind >::other>::iterator, bool> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(_Pair&&) [with _Pair = _Pair;  = ; _Key = int; _Tp = int; _Compare = std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >]
         insert(_Pair&& __x)
         ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:739:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:32:28: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
         m.insert(edges,dist);
                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/map:61:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/stdc++.h:81,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:752:7: note: candidate: void std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::initializer_list >) [with _Key = int; _Tp = int; _Compare = std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >]
       insert(std::initializer_list<value_type> __list)
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:752:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:781:7: note: candidate: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, const value_type&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = int; _Compare = std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = std::pair]
       insert(const_iterator __position, const value_type& __x)
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:781:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::pair’ to ‘std::map::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >}’
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:792:9: note: candidate: template std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, _Pair&&) [with _Pair = _Pair;  = ; _Key = int; _Tp = int; _Compare = std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >]
         insert(const_iterator __position, _Pair&& __x)
         ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:792:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:32:28: note:   cannot convert ‘edges’ (type ‘std::pair’) to type ‘std::map::const_iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >}’
         m.insert(edges,dist);
                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/map:61:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/stdc++.h:81,
                 from main.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:807:9: note: candidate: template void std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = _InputIterator; _Key = int; _Tp = int; _Compare = std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >]
         insert(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)
         ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:807:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:32:28: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_InputIterator’ (‘std::pair’ and ‘int’)
         m.insert(edges,dist);
                            ^
```

Being relatively new in programming, I am unable to understand head or tail of this message, your valuable inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `edges` is a `pair<int,int>`, but you are trying to put it into the map's `int`.

Comment: Oh right, so the map declaration should be map<pair<int,int>,int> right?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use an edge as a key in the map.

Comment: Why are you using a mix of styles (`vector<int> graph[n];`)? This is non-standard C++. You could use `vector<vector<int>) graph(n);` then pass it by reference to `add_edge`.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on "non-standard C++" ? I used an array of vector of arrays in order to make a sort of linked list, where each vector in the array corresponds to what elements are attatched to vertex of index ' i ' of the array. And making an array seems more advantageous to me as memory is already allocated for it, unlike in the case of vectors. Please correct me if I am wrong though, I am not 100% sure about the last statement I just told. Thanks again.

Comment: `vector<int> graph[n];` is a variable-length array, the size isn't known at compile time. It isn't legal C++ but some compilers allow it as an extension from C. You're already using `std::vector` so you should use a vector of vectors instead.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification.